# UpSetR sets.bar interacting different color and its sets intersections

Tags: r, upsetr

hello I am creating upsetr plot not able figure out how can I plot the data as show in below image
[image]

I saw different plot making similar to this but not same, Can any one suggest me an easy way to do it and seen some of the threads not able reproduce few according my above image kind output

[UpSetR group by color set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430902/upsetr-group-by-color-set)

[Use a color palette for matrix points in UpSetR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223273/use-a-color-palette-for-matrix-points-in-upsetr)

[blog post](http://research.libd.org/rstatsclub/post/hacking-our-way-through-upsetr/#.YHb_dvszZrk)

Thank you

Comment: Would you consider answers using [ComplexUpset](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/) instead, or are you looking for UpSetR solution only?

Comment: @krassowski Thank you for the reply anything will be fine

Comment: @krassowski  I tried ComplexUpset R but not able get what I want can you please help me figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reproduce this plot using ComplexUpset 1.3 or newer.

Prepare the dataset:

```
movies = ggplot2movies::movies
movies[movies$mpaa == '', 'mpaa'] = NA 
movies = movies[complete.cases(movies), ]
```

And plot:

```
upset(
  movies,
  c('Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama'),
  queries=list(
    upset_query(set='Action', fill='orange'),
    upset_query(set='Comedy', fill='blue'),
    upset_query(set='Drama', fill='coral3')
  ),
  base_annotations=list(
    'Intersection size'=(
        intersection_size(
        bar_number_threshold=1,  # show all numbers on top of bars
        width=0.5,   # reduce width of the bars
      )
      # add some space on the top of the bars
      + scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(mult=c(0, 0.05)))
      + theme(
          # hide grid lines
          panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
          # show axis lines
          axis.line=element_line(colour='black')
      )
    )
  ),
  stripes=upset_stripes(
    geom=geom_segment(size=12),  # make the stripes larger
    colors=c('grey95', 'white')
  ),
  # to prevent connectors from getting the colorured
  # use `fill` instead of `color`, together with `shape='circle filled'`
  matrix=intersection_matrix(
      geom=geom_point(
        shape='circle filled',
        size=3.5,
        stroke=0.45
      )
  ),
  set_sizes=(
    upset_set_size(geom=geom_bar(width=0.4))
    + theme(
      axis.line.x=element_line(colour='black'),
      axis.ticks.x=element_line()
    )
  ),
  sort_sets='ascending',
  sort_intersections='ascending'
)
```

[image: UpSetR equivalent plot]